# scrapy xpath: can't get google next page

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to get next page in `https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=test`

But my code not work.
Please guide me. Thank you so much.

```
  scrapy shell "https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=test"
 response.xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']/@href")
```

Comment: you are not receiving the page you are looking for. Use command view(response) to open the browser

Answer (score 2):

Here it is the working code

```
scrapy shell "https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=test"
response.xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']/@href")
```

The issue was in the way you were making the request to google.

In any case be aware about the policy dealing with Google search.

Google's Custom Search Terms of Service (TOS) can be found at http://www.google.com/cse/docs/tos.html.

**UPDATE:**
I wrote down a spider to test more in deep this issue.

Not pythonic at all (improvements are welcome), but I was interested in the mechanism of dealing with google results.

As previous comments suggested, a test for the internationalization of the interface is needed.

```
class googleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "googlish"
    allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.com"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)      
        login_form = self.driver.find_element_by_name('q')        
        login_form.send_keys("scrapy\n")
        time.sleep(4)
        found = False
        while not found:
            try :
                for element in self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rc']"):
                    print element.text + "\n"
                for i in self.driver.find_elements_by_id('pnnext'):
                    i.click()
                time.sleep(5)        
            except NoSuchElementException:
                found = True
                pass

        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: @alecxe interesting worth a deeper analysis. do you have any clue about the reason ? I took out the xpath from the google inspecting tools and applied it in the shell command and it worked. what happen if you visualize the page by the shell command ? Is it the correct page ?

Comment: Thanks, if I do `view(response)` I actually see the search results and there is a next button at the bottom, though it doesn't have the `pnnext` id: `<a href="/search?q=test&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;prmd=ivnsa&amp;ei=XJTCVOXlL4vvgwSjjISIBA&amp;start=10&amp;sa=N" style="text-align:left"><span class="csb" style="background-position:-96px 0;width:71px"></span><span style="display:block;margin-left:53px">�U�@��</span></a>`.

Comment: @alecxe not so expert about google search but it sounds as a strange behavior. this way it would be needed a different approach like searching for the "next" label

Comment: @alexce tried a different approach using webdriver to extract the next page of results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using below x path and let me know what the result is.Looks like the the xpath used is not pointing to the exact location of web-element in the DOM.

```
//a[@id='pnnext']//span[2]
```

Comment: are you sure about this solution ?  It results []

Comment: @aberna : I agree with you to use command view(response), but i also checked in the DOM for the Web-Element , I found Span[2] may be more precise to be pointed.